# How to looping number of columns same as value of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

i want to make loop put value in the columns sam as number value
when number in array

but the problem is too many columns are empty

my code is

```
$answer = [1]=> "B" [2]=> "D" [3]=> "C" [7]=> "C" [8]=> "C" [9]=> "C" [10]=> "C"];
for ($i=1; $i <= 25 ;$i++){
            foreach ($answers as $no => $value) {
                    if ($no == $i) {
                        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                      }else {
                        echo "<td></td>";
                   }
                }
             } 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwgFq.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one loop.

If you are only interested in the present values in $answers, just use the inner loop.

```
foreach ($answers as $no => $value) {
    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
}
```

If you want to print out 25 `<td>`s including an empty ones when the values in `$answers` are not present, then you use the outer loop. However you can reference an index in `$answers` array by `$answers[index]`, so `$answers[1]` will be "B", and so on. So for each index from 1 to 25, it can be referenced by `$answers[$i]`.

When the value is not present in a given index, for example at index 4, `$answers[4]` will give you an error. You can check for it and give a default value e.g. `$answers[4] ?? ''` will instead give an empty string and not throw an error.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 25; $i++) {
    echo "<td>" .($answers[$i] ?? '') ."</td>";
}
```